# Why does import readline() fail

Tags: windows, python-3.x, readline

What I've tried:

```
    Python 3.7 (64-bit) interactive window [PTVS 15.7.18156.1-15.0]
    Type `$help` for a list of commands.
    >>> import readline
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
    >>>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

As @eryksun helpfully pointed out in the comments (which have since been removed), the `readline` package is not bundled with Python for Windows. You have to install `pyreadline` instead using `pip` in the command line:

```
pip install pyreadline
```

Comment: I put pyreadline under scripts, but my environ interactive window [PTVS 15.7.18156.1-15.0]
Type $help for a list of commands.
>>> 
>>> import pip
>>> pip install pyreadline
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    
    pip install pyreadline
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax , i think install isn't supported. What can I do?  help> pip install
No Python documentation found for 'pip install'.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You should run `pip` in command line, not your python shell or IDE.

Comment: Still get same return prompts executing from cmd

Comment: oops, I am running python37-32 which is ide. I'll have to change my paths.

Comment: You have to run this from the command line of your OS, not from Python.

Comment: I edited paths for Scripts and python executable, ran same commands as before and get the same results. When I downloaded python I didn't opt for idle. I think the problem is "install" because error prompt points to install. How do I fix this? As before I pyreadline under Scripts. I want to know how to install modules. I've been googling for gnu read, etc and reading python docs, perusing in youtube, but step-by-step are hard to come by.Thank for your help.

Comment: Again, please run this directly in the command line. Don't run Python at all. And by command line I mean the command prompt in Windows, or bash in Linux, or Terminal Application in Mac OS. https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-start-command-prompt-complete/

Comment: I created folder clipboard under pyreadline folder
pip install pyreadline ,
opened up cmd and did what you said. 
running install_lib
copying build\lib\pyreadline\clipboard\ironpython_clipboard.py
-> c:\program files\python37\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline

\clipbpoard
error; could not create 'c:\\program files\python\Lib\site-

packages\pyreadline\clipboard\ironpython_clipboard.py': Permission denied, getting closer